How to drag card up entirely from the bottom of the card instead of just the left point?
I'm making a card game in 2D where the player can "peek" at their cards. I am currently using the Book - Page Curl tool and have rotated it -90 degrees on the Z-Axis.

It's almost the result that I want, but I cannot figure out how to drag the card up from the entire bottom edge of the card, not just one of the corners.
Here is my code:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
public enum FlipMode
{
    RightToLeft,
    LeftToRight
}
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Book : MonoBehaviour {
    public Canvas canvas;
    [SerializeField]
    RectTransform BookPanel;
    public Sprite background;
    public Sprite[] bookPages;
    public bool interactable=true;
    public bool enableShadowEffect=true;
    //represent the index of the sprite shown in the right page
    public int currentPage = 0;
    public int TotalPageCount
    {
        get { return bookPages.Length; }
    }
    public Vector3 EndBottomLeft
    {
        get { return ebl; }
    }
    public Vector3 EndBottomRight
    {
        get { return ebr; }
    }
    public float Height
    {
        get
        {
            return BookPanel.rect.height ; 
        }
    }
    public Image ClippingPlane;
    public Image NextPageClip;
    public Image Shadow;
    public Image ShadowLTR;
    public Image Left;
    public Image LeftNext;
    public Image Right;
    public Image RightNext;
    public UnityEvent OnFlip;
    float radius1, radius2;
    //Spine Bottom
    Vector3 sb;
    //Spine Top
    Vector3 st;
    //corner of the page
    Vector3 c;
    //Edge Bottom Right
    Vector3 ebr;
    //Edge Bottom Left
    Vector3 ebl;
    //follow point 
    Vector3 f;
    bool pageDragging = false;
    //current flip mode
    FlipMode mode;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!canvas) canvas=GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
        if (!canvas) Debug.LogError("Book should be a child to canvas");

        Left.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Right.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        UpdateSprites();
        CalcCurlCriticalPoints();

        float pageWidth = BookPanel.rect.width / 2.0f;
        float pageHeight = BookPanel.rect.height;
        NextPageClip.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(pageWidth, pageHeight + pageHeight * 2);


        ClippingPlane.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(pageWidth * 2 + pageHeight, pageHeight + pageHeight * 2);

        //hypotenous (diagonal) page length
        float hyp = Mathf.Sqrt(pageWidth * pageWidth + pageHeight * pageHeight);
        float shadowPageHeight = pageWidth / 2 + hyp;

        Shadow.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(pageWidth, shadowPageHeight);
        Shadow.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(1, (pageWidth / 2) / shadowPageHeight);

        ShadowLTR.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(pageWidth, shadowPageHeight);
        ShadowLTR.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0, (pageWidth / 2) / shadowPageHeight);

    }

    private void CalcCurlCriticalPoints()
    {
        sb = new Vector3(0, -BookPanel.rect.height / 2);
        ebr = new Vector3(BookPanel.rect.width / 2, -BookPanel.rect.height / 2);
        ebl = new Vector3(-BookPanel.rect.width / 2, -BookPanel.rect.height / 2);
        st = new Vector3(0, BookPanel.rect.height / 2);
        radius1 = Vector2.Distance(sb, ebr);
        float pageWidth = BookPanel.rect.width / 2.0f;
        float pageHeight = BookPanel.rect.height;
        radius2 = Mathf.Sqrt(pageWidth * pageWidth + pageHeight * pageHeight);
    }

    public Vector3 transformPoint(Vector3 mouseScreenPos)
    {
        if (canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera)
        {
            Vector3 mouseWorldPos = canvas.worldCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mouseScreenPos.x, mouseScreenPos.y, canvas.planeDistance));
            Vector2 localPos = BookPanel.InverseTransformPoint(mouseWorldPos);

            return localPos;
        }
        else if (canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.WorldSpace)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 globalEBR = transform.TransformPoint(ebr);
            Vector3 globalEBL = transform.TransformPoint(ebl);
            Vector3 globalSt = transform.TransformPoint(st);
            Plane p = new Plane(globalEBR, globalEBL, globalSt);
            float distance;
            p.Raycast(ray, out distance);
            Vector2 localPos = BookPanel.InverseTransformPoint(ray.GetPoint(distance));
            return localPos;
        }
        else
        {
            //Screen Space Overlay
            Vector2 localPos = BookPanel.InverseTransformPoint(mouseScreenPos);
            return localPos;
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (pageDragging && interactable)
        {
            UpdateBook();
        }
    }
    public void UpdateBook()
    {
        f = Vector3.Lerp(f, transformPoint(Input.mousePosition), Time.deltaTime * 10);
        if (mode == FlipMode.RightToLeft)
            UpdateBookRTLToPoint(f);
        else
            UpdateBookLTRToPoint(f);
    }
    public void UpdateBookLTRToPoint(Vector3 followLocation)
    {
        mode = FlipMode.LeftToRight;
        f = followLocation;
        ShadowLTR.transform.SetParent(ClippingPlane.transform, true);
        ShadowLTR.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        ShadowLTR.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Left.transform.SetParent(ClippingPlane.transform, true);

        Right.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        Right.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        LeftNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);

        c = Calc_C_Position(followLocation);
        Vector3 t1;
        float clipAngle = CalcClipAngle(c, ebl, out t1);
        //0 < T0_T1_Angle < 180
        clipAngle = (clipAngle + 180) % 180;

        ClippingPlane.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, clipAngle - 90);
        ClippingPlane.transform.position = BookPanel.TransformPoint(t1);

        //page position and angle
        Left.transform.position = BookPanel.TransformPoint(c);
        float C_T1_dy = t1.y - c.y;
        float C_T1_dx = t1.x - c.x;
        float C_T1_Angle = Mathf.Atan2(C_T1_dy, C_T1_dx) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Left.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, C_T1_Angle - 90 - clipAngle);

        NextPageClip.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, clipAngle - 90);
        NextPageClip.transform.position = BookPanel.TransformPoint(t1);
        LeftNext.transform.SetParent(NextPageClip.transform, true);
        Right.transform.SetParent(ClippingPlane.transform, true);
        Right.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();

        ShadowLTR.rectTransform.SetParent(Left.rectTransform, true);
    }
    public void UpdateBookRTLToPoint(Vector3 followLocation)
    {
        mode = FlipMode.RightToLeft;
        f = followLocation;
        Shadow.transform.SetParent(ClippingPlane.transform, true);
        Shadow.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        Shadow.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        Right.transform.SetParent(ClippingPlane.transform, true);

        Left.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        Left.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        RightNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        c = Calc_C_Position(followLocation);
        Vector3 t1;
        float clipAngle = CalcClipAngle(c, ebr, out t1);
        if (clipAngle > -90) clipAngle += 180;

        ClippingPlane.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(1, 0.35f);
        ClippingPlane.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, clipAngle + 90);
        ClippingPlane.transform.position = BookPanel.TransformPoint(t1);

        //page position and angle
        Right.transform.position = BookPanel.TransformPoint(c);
        float C_T1_dy = t1.y - c.y;
        float C_T1_dx = t1.x - c.x;
        float C_T1_Angle = Mathf.Atan2(C_T1_dy, C_T1_dx) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Right.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, C_T1_Angle - (clipAngle + 90));

        NextPageClip.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, clipAngle + 90);
        NextPageClip.transform.position = BookPanel.TransformPoint(t1);
        RightNext.transform.SetParent(NextPageClip.transform, true);
        Left.transform.SetParent(ClippingPlane.transform, true);
        Left.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();

        Shadow.rectTransform.SetParent(Right.rectTransform, true);
    }
    private float CalcClipAngle(Vector3 c,Vector3 bookCorner,out  Vector3 t1)
    {
        Vector3 t0 = (c + bookCorner) / 2;
        float T0_CORNER_dy = bookCorner.y - t0.y;
        float T0_CORNER_dx = bookCorner.x - t0.x;
        float T0_CORNER_Angle = Mathf.Atan2(T0_CORNER_dy, T0_CORNER_dx);
        float T0_T1_Angle = 90 - T0_CORNER_Angle;
        
        float T1_X = t0.x - T0_CORNER_dy * Mathf.Tan(T0_CORNER_Angle);
        T1_X = normalizeT1X(T1_X, bookCorner, sb);
        t1 = new Vector3(T1_X, sb.y, 0);
        
        //clipping plane angle=T0_T1_Angle
        float T0_T1_dy = t1.y - t0.y;
        float T0_T1_dx = t1.x - t0.x;
        T0_T1_Angle = Mathf.Atan2(T0_T1_dy, T0_T1_dx) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        return T0_T1_Angle;
    }
    private float normalizeT1X(float t1,Vector3 corner,Vector3 sb)
    {
        if (t1 > sb.x && sb.x > corner.x)
            return sb.x;
        if (t1 < sb.x && sb.x < corner.x)
            return sb.x;
        return t1;
    }
    private Vector3 Calc_C_Position(Vector3 followLocation)
    {
        Vector3 c;
        f = followLocation;
        float F_SB_dy = f.y - sb.y;
        float F_SB_dx = f.x - sb.x;
        float F_SB_Angle = Mathf.Atan2(F_SB_dy, F_SB_dx);
        Vector3 r1 = new Vector3(radius1 * Mathf.Cos(F_SB_Angle),radius1 * Mathf.Sin(F_SB_Angle), 0) + sb;

        float F_SB_distance = Vector2.Distance(f, sb);
        if (F_SB_distance < radius1)
            c = f;
        else
            c = r1;
        float F_ST_dy = c.y - st.y;
        float F_ST_dx = c.x - st.x;
        float F_ST_Angle = Mathf.Atan2(F_ST_dy, F_ST_dx);
        Vector3 r2 = new Vector3(radius2 * Mathf.Cos(F_ST_Angle),
           radius2 * Mathf.Sin(F_ST_Angle), 0) + st;
        float C_ST_distance = Vector2.Distance(c, st);
        if (C_ST_distance > radius2)
            c = r2;
        return c;
    }
    public void DragRightPageToPoint(Vector3 point)
    {
        if (currentPage >= bookPages.Length) return;
        pageDragging = true;
        mode = FlipMode.RightToLeft;
        f = point;


        NextPageClip.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0, 0.12f);
        ClippingPlane.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(1, 0.35f);

        Left.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Left.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0, 0);
        Left.transform.position = RightNext.transform.position;
        Left.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Left.sprite = (currentPage < bookPages.Length) ? bookPages[currentPage] : background;
        Left.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
        
        Right.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Right.transform.position = RightNext.transform.position;
        Right.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Right.sprite = (currentPage < bookPages.Length - 1) ? bookPages[currentPage + 1] : background;

        RightNext.sprite = (currentPage < bookPages.Length - 2) ? bookPages[currentPage + 2] : background;

        LeftNext.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
        if (enableShadowEffect) Shadow.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UpdateBookRTLToPoint(f);
    }
    public void OnMouseDragRightPage()
    {
        if (interactable)
        DragRightPageToPoint(transformPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        
    }
    public void DragLeftPageToPoint(Vector3 point)
    {
        if (currentPage <= 0) return;
        pageDragging = true;
        mode = FlipMode.LeftToRight;
        f = point;

        NextPageClip.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(1, 0.12f);
        ClippingPlane.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0, 0.35f);

        Right.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Right.transform.position = LeftNext.transform.position;
        Right.sprite = bookPages[currentPage - 1];
        Right.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Right.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();

        Left.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Left.rectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(1, 0);
        Left.transform.position = LeftNext.transform.position;
        Left.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Left.sprite = (currentPage >= 2) ? bookPages[currentPage - 2] : background;

        LeftNext.sprite = (currentPage >= 3) ? bookPages[currentPage - 3] : background;

        RightNext.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
        if (enableShadowEffect) ShadowLTR.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UpdateBookLTRToPoint(f);
    }
    public void OnMouseDragLeftPage()
    {
        if (interactable)
        DragLeftPageToPoint(transformPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        
    }
    public void OnMouseRelease()
    {
        if (interactable)
            ReleasePage();
    }
    public void ReleasePage()
    {
        if (pageDragging)
        {
            pageDragging = false;
            float distanceToLeft = Vector2.Distance(c, ebl);
            float distanceToRight = Vector2.Distance(c, ebr);
            if (distanceToRight < distanceToLeft && mode == FlipMode.RightToLeft)
                TweenBack();
            else if (distanceToRight > distanceToLeft && mode == FlipMode.LeftToRight)
                TweenBack();
            else
                TweenBack();
        }
    }
    Coroutine currentCoroutine;
    void UpdateSprites()
    {
        LeftNext.sprite= (currentPage > 0 && currentPage <= bookPages.Length) ? bookPages[currentPage-1] : background;
        RightNext.sprite=(currentPage>=0 &&currentPage<bookPages.Length) ? bookPages[currentPage] : background;
    }
    public void TweenForward()
    {
        if(mode== FlipMode.RightToLeft)
        currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(TweenTo(ebl, 0.15f, () => { Flip(); }));
        else
        currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(TweenTo(ebr, 0.15f, () => { Flip(); }));
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        if (mode == FlipMode.RightToLeft)
            currentPage += 2;
        else
            currentPage -= 2;
        LeftNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        Left.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        LeftNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        Left.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Right.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Right.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        RightNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform, true);
        UpdateSprites();
        Shadow.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        ShadowLTR.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        if (OnFlip != null)
            OnFlip.Invoke();
    }
    public void TweenBack()
    {
        if (mode == FlipMode.RightToLeft)
        {
            currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(TweenTo(ebr,0.15f,
                () =>
                {
                    UpdateSprites();
                    RightNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform);
                    Right.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform);

                    Left.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    Right.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    pageDragging = false;
                }
                ));
        }
        else
        {
            currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(TweenTo(ebl, 0.15f,
                () =>
                {
                    UpdateSprites();

                    LeftNext.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform);
                    Left.transform.SetParent(BookPanel.transform);

                    Left.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    Right.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    pageDragging = false;
                }
                ));
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator TweenTo(Vector3 to, float duration, System.Action onFinish)
    {
        int steps = (int)(duration / 0.025f);
        Vector3 displacement = (to - f) / steps;
        for (int i = 0; i < steps-1; i++)
        {
            if(mode== FlipMode.RightToLeft)
            UpdateBookRTLToPoint( f + displacement);
            else
                UpdateBookLTRToPoint(f + displacement);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.025f);
        }
        if (onFinish != null)
            onFinish();
    }
}`


I tried to modify the DragRightPageToPoint function with:
public void DragRightPageToPoint(Vector3 touchPosition)
{
  if (currentPage >= bookPages.Length) return;

  // Check if touch position is within the right side threshold area
  if (touchPosition.x > BookPanel.rect.width * 0.75f) // Adjust threshold value as needed (0 to 1)
  {
    pageDragging = true;
    mode = FlipMode.RightToLeft;
    f = touchPosition;

    // Rest of the code remains the same...
  }
}

but yielded no results. I doubt that i am going in the correct direction

The placement of an element is (usually) dictated by changing Left and Top. If you click anywhere except (0,0) you need to offset any coordinate changes (dragging) by the relative offsets of the "pointer position" from (0,0), when the "pointer/mouse" first came "down". And you keep that offset while dragging (until the mouse/pointer is released)

Is that your code or Abdullah Aldandarawy's code from the package you are using?

If you want to resize the area that the user can drag the page from it, open the Book node in inspector to show its children, you will find two objects "RightHotSpot" and "LeftHotSpot" resize them and set their anchors as required.
